# django internazionalization within a dictionary structure

Tags: python, django, dictionary, translation

I have a django app with internazionalization working right, but now I came up to an issue I can't find a solution/answer.

All the translation is working right within views and templates by following the instructions from: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19.html

But the issue is in the views I have dictionary structures like:

```
mensajes = {'powered-antiguo' : 'Tecnologia del sitio conocida y antigua.',
            'server-antiguo'  : 'Servidor web conocido y antiguo.',
            .... cut ...
```

but trying translation like:

```
mensajes = {'powered-antiguo' : 'Tecnologia del sitio conocida y antigua.',
            'server-antiguo'  : _('Servidor web conocido y antiguo.'),
```

after the makemessages and compilation all its correct, I got the text to translate but the app is not showing the translation.

Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do string identifiers exist in resulting files after you've run `makemessages`?

Comment: Wich is the active language when you expect to see any translation ?  Did you use `translation.activate(LANGUAGE_CODE)` to change active language ?